# Combine variable and for each loop python

Tags: python, python-2.5

Is there a way to make this pythonic.

```
the_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for x in the_list
   y= get_handler(x)
   #do something with x and y
```

Basically is there a simpler way to put the get_handler in the for deceleration?

ideally something readable like:

```
for x, get_handler(x) in the_list:
    #do whatever
```

A working, but non readable solution:

```
the_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for x, y in [(item, get_handler(item) for item in the_list )]:   
   # do something
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: IMHO the first example is more pythonic as it is more readable and you are not constructing an unnecessary list that you just throw away later.

Comment: It works, but it just seems like there is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Shorter, but not simpler or better: `for x, y in zip(the_list, map(get_handler, the_list)):`.  Or perhaps with a lambda: `for x, y in map(lambda x:(x, get_handler(x)), the_list)`.  But seriously, stick with your first, perfectly clear approach.

Comment: agreed, but I was hoping for a syntax i didn't know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "pythonic" means how normal python code would look like (see gnibbler's answer: that is what "pythonic" is about).

If you want something that will do exactly what you want, you can do:

```
def zipMap(func, iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        yield x,func(x)
```

Then:

```
for x,y in zipMap(get_handler, the_list):
    ...
```

Do note that this doesn't save you any typing at all. The only way it would save you typing is if you were using it for *currying*:

```
def withHandler(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        yield x,get_handler(x)
```

In which case it *does* save you typing:

```
for x,y in withHandler(the_list):
    ...
```

Thus it might be reasonable if you happened to use it a lot. It would not be considered "pythonic" though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, put a colon at the end of the `for` line, a space after the `y`, and use 4 spaces for your indenting :)

```
the_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for x in the_list: 
    y = get_handler(x)
    # do something with x and y
```

Comment: Never have I liked a sarcastic-ish answer so much... because never before have I seen one that's so literally what was asked for. =)